# How to distinguish among nodes running on a same machine in a p2p network, socket in language C

Tags: c, sockets, network-programming, p2p

I would like to build a completed network(every node connects to remaining nodes). I have a group of peers, let say it includes P2P1, P2P2, P2P3. Assuming that all peers are running on a same machine(localhost). Every peer has a client side and server side that are written in a same file.

First P2P1 is initialized as "p2p Name_of_group Port_Number_for_Server_Side". Then
P2P2 as "p2p Name_of_group Port_Number_for_Server_Side Port_Number_of_P2P1". And then
P2P3 as "p2p Name_of_group Port_Number_for_Server_Side Port_Number_of_P2P2".

The client side of P2P2 connects to the server side of P2P1, the client side of P2P3 connects to the server side of P2P2.

Now P2P1 connects to P2P3(automatically in code , not from user). If there is a new peer, let say P2P4, also would like to connect to P2P1(by user). How can I distinguish between P2P3 as an old peer and P2P4 as a new peer since both of them at the first time only connect() to P2P1(not send() yet)?.

Moreover, I considered to use "hostname:port" to distinguish among them but since they are running on a same machine(hostname is similar), and port is client port(not server port that is unique to every peer, every peer has many client ports). When P2P2 connects to P2P1, P2P1 is informed P2P2 joined the group(including P2P1 and P2P2). When  P2P3 connects to P2P2, P2P2 is informed P2P3 joined the group. However, the name of P2P2 at P2P1 is different with the name of P2P2 at P2P3 since client port of P2P2 connecting to P2P1 is different with it of P2P2 connecting to P2P3. I want a unique name for P2P2, how can I do that? Thanks very much for your comment.

Comment: Why wouldn't you use the server port? It's unique and persistent per session per peer, which sounds like what you're describing. Alternatively, there are a few [UUID schemes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_Unique_Identifier) around.

Comment: Hi John, the problem is I couldn't get the server port by getpeername() or getinfoname() since, for example, the client side of P2P2 connects to server side of P2P1, so at P2P1 I'm only able to get client port of P2P2. In getpeername(), the sin_port returns the port of client side of P2P2 that P2P1 is connecting with.

Comment: Ah, that makes more sense. Right, there's nothing in a client connection that identifies anything else about the client, so you'll have to build that into your application's protocol. That's probably good, though, because you can send each peer anything it can use.

Answer (score 0):

Honestly you lost me in your naming scheme.

Let me rephrase the question.

```
A server accepts two connections. Is there a way to tell that both
connections are initiated by the same agent?
```

If this is the question you want to be answered, the answer is no. The only information a server has at that moment is what is returned by `getpeername`, which in your scheme of things doesn't identify the connecting agent.

You may consider assigning each agent a separate range of client ports. Or adding a handshake phase to your protocol.

Comment: I mean, If I stay at a peer, I would like to get the unique names of  other peers such that if I stay at another peer, I still see the unique names of peers in a group. For example, when P2P2 connects to P2P1, the client side of P2P1 will connect and communicate with client side of P2P2. At P2P1, if I use getpeername(), I'm able to get the client port of P2P2. However, P2P2 has many client ports since it connects to many peers, so when at P2P1, if I list the current peers in a group, the name of  other peers will be different with these if I list them at P2P2.